# Wordpress - Display a post a week in advance

Tags: php, wordpress

- I have a speakers category
- Each speaker is set up as a post
- The wordpress published date, is the date they are coming to speak (so most speakers posts are "scheduled")
- There is a new speaker each week (every 7 days)
- On my speakers page I display the "featured speaker of the week" which contains all the post information
- Underneath the featured speaker, is a list of upcoming speakers (just the title, not the whole post)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the "Featured Speaker", only show up for a week (including the day they are speaking), and once the day after they have spoken comes, it will show the next person speaking on the site for a week until they have spoken and so on and so forth.

I'm getting stumped on the logic. I was doing well until I hit:

> if($postdatenum >= $todaynum + 6)

Which will not work when it's a different month.

I know my code is convoluted and probably outdated, but if anyone can shed some light on the logic for calculating the 7 days thing, that would be awesome.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'speakers',
    'showposts' => 1,
    'order' => DESC
    ) );  

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="">
<?php 
$today = date('m/d');
$postdate = the_date('m/d','','',FALSE);
//IF POST DATE AND TODAYS DATE NOT THE SAME
if($postdate != $today){

    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_status' => 'future',
        'showposts' => 1,
        'order' => ASC
        ) );  
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $todaynum = date('d'); //10
    $postdatenum = the_date('d','','',FALSE); //17

    if($postdatenum >= $todaynum + 6){
?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(('medium'), array('class' => 'alignright')); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php
    }

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();

}else{
?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(('medium'), array('class' => 'alignright')); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
} endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: You have HTML inside your PHP tags. That will not work.

Comment: yea sorry, that was a mistake..**Edited**

Comment: why don't you use a custom field for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strtotime and date

```
if($postdatenum >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today' . '+6 days') ) )
```

not sure what format you are using but look here for diff formats http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. You **obviously cant use just the day because months and years are involved.**

Comment: Thanks for the +6 day thing, I didn't know you could do that. I reworked my code using that, and it almost works perfect. Now the only problem is my date's won't show up in the "upcoming dates" table. I'm thinking maybe because I messed with the dates? I made a fiddle with my updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/b7z2nz05/ and here's my website so you can see it displayed: http://www.bnidynamo.com/speakers/

Comment: I've tried just "the_date();" and "the_date('m, Y');" etc, and it never shows the date.

Comment: try echo the_date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Notice that `the_date()` with one argument will not **return** the value, only when the *fourth* argument is `false`.

Comment: @birgire yes I realize the one in the fiddle doesn't work, but like I said I've been trying a bunch of other date methods and none of them are working.

Comment: true, overlooked that... @keryn are you saying $postdate or $postdatenum is empty or it wont display in your template? btw is this http://www.bnidynamo.com/speakers/ a single post template? or will there be more posts on the page?

Comment: its ok i found the issue http://jsfiddle.net/b7z2nz05/4/ aparently the_date() will only return the same date once on a page. You can use the var $postdate you set earlier. i tidied up the code a small bit hopefully its the same. btw i suggest using a full date format so instead of 'd/m' 'd/m/Y' as in late december your code will fail..

Comment: Thanks @David I used your code and kind of mashed it with what I had and it work's great! Added a year, and day of week to my date query so I could get the parameters I needed later on, and then fudged how to display it with split string. http://jsfiddle.net/96yanvwa/

Comment: well done. Btw, 'Y-m-d' = the format you are looking for or  'd-m-Y', etc. Next time try something big bigire solution you can find details here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query wp_query has a lot more options for returning posts and is virtually the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this trick with the `date_query` will work for you as a single query (untested):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish', 'future' ),
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'category_name'  => 'speakers',
    'date_query'     => array(
         array(
             'before'    => '+13days',
             'after'     => '-1days',
             'inclusive' => true,
         ),
     ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The first post from this query should be the current speaker this week and the other post after that will be the upcoming speaker.

If you want to include more upcoming speakers, you can increase the `posts_per_page` and increase the number of days in `before` parameter.

So no need for more than a single query.

ps: Don't use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), it's not recommended, check for example this quote from [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

### Example:

Let's assume the lectures always starts at 12:00 pm each week.

Then we mark the speakers (A, B, C, D, E, ... ) on the calendar:

```
Jan 2014                                                                                    Feb 2014
          A                  B                      C                      D                    E
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 | 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 | 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 | 29 30 31 1 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 8 9 10
                  -  *  +  +  +  +    +  +  +  +  +  +  +    +  +   
                    -  *   +  +  +  +    +  +  +  +  +  +  +    +  +  
                       -  *   +  +  +  +    +  +  +  +  +  +  +    +  +  
                           -  *  +  +  +  +    +  +  +  +  +  +  +    +  +
```

Sorry for the mismatched +/- and the current day * in the above. It's just an example how you can mark the calendar.

Then we can construct the following list from the above query:

```
Day Time Speaker
------------

 ...

 5 12:00 AB
 5 12:01 AB

 6 12:00 AB
 6 12:01 AB

 7 12:00 AB
 7 12:01 BC

 8 12:00 BC
 8 12:01 BC

 ...  

12 12:00 BC
12 12:01 BC

13 12:00 BC
13 12:01 CD

14 12:00 CD
14 12:01 CD

 ...
```